# represent string in 2D plot

Tags: java, string, matlab, plot, cluster-analysis

I have a clustering software where pattern is string of characters.
The strings are grouped by similarity using longest common subsequence. 
It's possible to make a 2d plot of this clusters ?? How can I represent a string on xy axis ??

The only idea that I have is to use ascii code in order to have an integer from string, for example:
red= 315 
becouse r=114 e=101 d=100

but this it's 1D representation !!

p.s. the software is Java , but for plot data I usually use Matlab

Answer (score 2):

There are infinitely many ways to convert a string to a number. Essentially it is just a sequence of bytes, so they already are numbers.

The question is, what do you want to *see*? Most of these "conversions" will be all over the place, and not actually convey much meaning.

Two techniques that come to my mind are self-organizing maps and multidimensional scaling. You can probably feed the similarity data into the method, and have it arrange the objects in a 2D map for you.

That will probably work and look, pretty, but doesn't really answer the question "what do you want to achieve".

Comment: If it's possible I want see point in a 2d plot, example:
the point that represent the word "induction" can be near the point of word "intrusion". The question is how represent "induction" in a 2d space ?

Comment: Have a look at the pointers I gave above, such as MDS. It is meant to preserve distances, and you could initialize it with Levenshtein distance.